# Sending email in Delphi without smtp and using php function at server

Tags: php, delphi, email

Using Delphi, i want to send a text message to my web server using winsock, and then use an email php function on the server to post the message.

First i have done the sending procedure (Procedure SendEmail): it reads a text file (log) and POST it to my server. On the server, the message is received by aa email php function named email.php (see content of that function below):

```
Procedure SendEmail;

var
WSADat:WSAData; // winsock.pas
Texto:TextFile;
Client:TSocket;
Info,Posting,Linha,Content:String;
SockAddrIn:SockAddr_In; // winsock.pas
begin
try
if not FileExists(Log) then exit;
AssignFile(Texto, Log); // text to be sent 
Reset(Texto);
while not Eof(Texto) do
begin
ReadLn(Texto, Linha);
Content:=Content+#13#10+Linha;
end;
CloseFile(Texto);
DeleteFile(PChar(Log));
WSAStartUp(257,WSADat);
Client:=Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_IP);
SockAddrIn.sin_family:=AF_INET;
SockAddrIn.sin_port:=htons(80);
SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr:=inet_addr('60.64.10.42'); // myserver IP
if Connect(Client,SockAddrIn,SizeOf(SockAddrIn))=0 then begin
Info:='Sender='+CFG.Email+'&content='+Content;
Posting:='POST /blogwp/email.php HTTP/1.0' #13#10
'Connection: close' #13#10
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' #13#10
'Content-Length: '+IntToStr(Length(Info)) #13#10
'Host: http://myserver.com' #13#10
'Accept: text/html' +#13#10+#13#10+
Info+#13#10;
Send(Client,Pointer(Posting)^,Length(Posting),0);
end;
CloseSocket(Client);
except
exit;
end;
end;
[... some  mutex test...]
end.
```

Description of email.php function on the server:

```
<?php
$to =$_POST["sender"];
$subject ="mymessages";
$message =$_POST["content"];
$from ="From: some at somedomain dot com";

$headers =implode("\n",array("From: $headers","Subject: $subject","Return-Path: $headers","MIME-Version: 1.0?","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html" ));

$flag = mail($to,$subject,$message,$from); // create variables

if($flag)
{
echo "ok!";
}
else
{
echo "no ok =/";
}
?>
```

(note:I have followed this guide for the php mail function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php )

The general idea here is to send the message to the server not using smtp. However, as far as i can see, it looks like the mail is dropped at my server. I'm pretty confident of the procedure, but not sure about the php mail function. The thing is not easy to debug. ANY idea what is going wrong? OR any other look alike solution?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[EDIT]
I have also ask support at my server site concerning use of smtp. Looks like i cannot send any mail (using smtp) if no check is done first:

> ```
> We use pop-before-smtp mail authentication. You first need to
> ```
>
> check the mail before you can send
> any. You also do not set smtp
> authentication in your e-mail client
> settings. Once you have checked the
> mail with POP authentication is not
> needed.
>
> ```
> We use POP before SMTP authentication as it is a fairly
> ```
>
> secure way to prevent spammers and
> open relays. Unfortunately, this is
> the configuration that we have chosen.
> For users who wish to send out mailing
> lists, we have the Mailman ValueApp,
> but for standard emailing, POP before
> SMTP is how the server is setup.

Comment: Why don't you use a web service into your server? The web service will collect the message data and sends the message. It's simpler and not socket oriented.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is wrong:

```
$headers =implode("\n",array("From: $headers","Subject: $subject","Return-Path: $headers","MIME-Version: 1.0?","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html" ));
```

It should be

```
$headers =implode("\r\n", array("From: $from","Return-Path: $from","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html"));
```

although your mail server may be broken and require "\n".

also $from should be the email address only, and not include "From: ".

There's no need to set a Subject header - PHP will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the case of the POST value names are matching - you have

```
$to =$_POST["sender"];
```

and

```
Info:='Sender='+CFG.Email
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you noted that the ISP requires authentication via POP-before-SMTP, you should look into using something like [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/) which can facilitate this kind of interaction - or roll your own using the PHP functions for [POP](http://php.net/imap) (which happen to be exactly the same as the ones for IMAP and NNTP).

Comment: Thanks - i will look at PHO Mailer. Otherwise, what will be a correct pop email checker? Is this ok POP :

<?php

$imap_obj = imap_check($imap_stream);
var_dump($imap_obj);

?>

Comment: From php.net/imap-open, you can see the 2nd example:

$mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:110/pop3}INBOX", "user_id", "password");

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP side you can use fsockopen(), fputs(), fgets(), and fclose() to handle your connection needs to the POP server. The PHP help for fsockopen() should give you the details you need.

Side note: Perhaps not an issue but you will want to make sure you have not created a hybrid of an open relay (letting others use your email.php endpoint for sending e-mail on your behalf).

Comment: Thanks, i wiull look and try fsockopen()

Answer (score 1):

**To test your PHP code**

Why don't you try writing to a file? 
I would write to a file on the server with the date/time and the logfile contents, then access it from http://myserver.com/log.txt

**As for the Delphi part:**

I wouldn't use sockets directly, Why don't you use libraries like Indy (TIDHTTP).

Using it would be much simpler.

The POST would be something like IdHttp1.Post(...)

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks ... I have applied the corrections. Now i have exactly:

```
Procedure EnviarEmail;
var
  WSADat:WSAData;
  Texto:TextFile;
  Client:TSocket;
  Info,Posting,Linha,Content:String;
  SockAddrIn:SockAddr_In;
begin
  try
    if not FileExists(Log) then exit;
    AssignFile(Texto, Log);
    Reset(Texto);
    while not Eof(Texto) do
    begin
      ReadLn(Texto, Linha);
      Content:=Content+#13#10+Linha;
    end;
    CloseFile(Texto);
    DeleteFile(PChar(Log));
    WSAStartUp(257,WSADat);
    Client:=Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_IP);
    SockAddrIn.sin_family:=AF_INET;
    SockAddrIn.sin_port:=htons(80);
    SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr:=inet_addr('86.88.10.42');
    if Connect(Client,SockAddrIn,SizeOf(SockAddrIn))=0 then begin
      Info:='Sender='+CFG.Email+'&Content='+Content;
      Posting:='POST /blogwp/email.php HTTP/1.0'               +#13#10+
             'Connection: close'                               +#13#10+
             'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' +#13#10+
             'Content-Length: '+IntToStr(Length(Info))         +#13#10+
             'Host: http://somedomain.com'                     +#13#10+
             'Accept: text/html'                               +#13#10+#13#10+
             Info+#13#10;
      Send(Client,Pointer(Posting)^,Length(Posting),0);
    end;
    CloseSocket(Client);
   // ShowMessage('INFO == ' +Info + ' POSTING == '+ Posting);
  except
    exit;
  end;
end;
[... some mutex check...]
```

The email.php on server is:

```
<?php
$to =$_POST["Sender"];
$subject ="mymessages";
$message =$_POST["content"];
$from ="From: some at somedomain dot com";

$headers =implode("\r\n", array("From: $from","Return-Path: $from","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html"));

$flag = mail($to,$subject,$message,$from); // create variables

if($flag)
{
echo "ok!";
}
else
{
echo "no ok =/";
}
?>
```

Still get no mail. ShowMessage in the procedure show me something like this for the info variable:

```
Sender=validEmailAddressContent=<..... data ....>
```

This might be wrong - at least a space or a line feed (?) is missing between the address and the content. How exactly should be formated this 'info' variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Please comment your posts instead of "answering" them.

Comment: I have managed to send mail using PEAR and this script: 

<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "name <email of name>";
$to = "name <email of name>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi";
$host = "smtp server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'user' => $username,
'pass' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message sent!</p>");
 }
?>